# Событие в Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Добрый вечер. У меня такой вопрос: есть несколько событий, обрабатываемых с помощью Jquery. Обработчики почему-то срабатывают только если они находятся внутри обработчика функции $(document).ready(). При этом когда-то довольно давно я писал в другом проекте обработчики, которые работали не будучи помещенными в функцию $(document).ready(). К сожалению тот проект не сохранился и посмотреть как это было там не могу.

Comment: поместите обработчики после `body`

Comment: я туплю наверное но после какого body?  того которое <body> </body>?

Comment: А чем же вам так мешает конструкция DOMReady? Кстати, она очень выручает тех, кто не знает после какого body можно поселить JS. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще говоря у вас скорее всего ситуация такая:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="myscript.js"> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mydiv">CLickme</div>
</body>
```

JS: (myscript.js)

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(){console.log(this);});
```

**то что сверху работать не будет**  т.к. скрипт выполнится раньше инициализации DOM.

обычная практика (которая к тому же прививает привычку не засорять global scope)

```
$(function () { // тоже самое что $(document).ready
    $('#mydiv').click(
    function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

либо

```
$(document).on('click', '#mydiv', // то что раньше называлось live
 function () {
    console.log(this);
 });
```

я лично рекомендую по отношению к id применять первый способ

помещать скрипт в body не рекомендую

Answer (score 0):

В $(document).ready() имеет смысл помещать события, которые зависят от DOM. Альтернатива ему это помещения всех скриптов перед тегом </body>. 
Соответственно, если ваш скрипт выполняет операции не связанные с DOM, то вы можете где угодно его поместить.